# Is it possible to reuse context-property placeholder as a supplier for an attribute that expects a <props> list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm defining my text properties by means of

```
<context:property-placeholder location="application.properties"/>
```

and then, I got something like

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:jpaProperties-ref="*****"/>
```

I like to feed a reference to the context property-placeholder, instead of using

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can use PropertiesFactoryBean like this:

```
    <bean id="jpaProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/jpa.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:jpaProperties-ref="japProperties"/>
```

Comment: Is it problematic if there is non-related properties in the file?

Comment: not at all, you can use your application.properties